# Replacing databases from previous to new one

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, streamreader

How can I replace my new database file to my previous database file?
My previous database is inside the folder :

```
 string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "Martyr.db";
```

My app code:

```
string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "Martyr.db";
string disPath;
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            disPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Martyr.db");
            WWW loadDB;
#if UNITY_ANDROID
            {
                loadDB = new WWW(disPath);
            }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            {
                loadDB = new WWW("file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Martyr.db");
            }
#else
            {loadDB=new WWW(dispath);}
#endif
#endif
            while (!loadDB.isDone)
            {
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, loadDB.bytes);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply delete your old Databasefile and write a new one.

```
            string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "Martyr.db";
            string disPath;
            if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }

            disPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Martyr.db");
            WWW loadDB;
#if UNITY_ANDROID
            {
                loadDB = new WWW(disPath);
            }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            {
                loadDB = new WWW("file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Martyr.db");
            }
#else
            {loadDB=new WWW(dispath);}
#endif
#endif
            while (!loadDB.isDone) {
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, loadDB.bytes);
```

Comment: it is not working.
I encounter this error  IOException: Sharing violation on path

Comment: Is your database still in use, when you try to delete it? Is it opened by any filestream or so?